# How to convert this SQL query into MDX query?

Tags: sql, mdx, pentaho, saiku

I'm using pentaho saiku analytic to perform cube analysis. But in some case, i need to build my own query with MDX query. below is my sql query.

```
select idAction,count(idAction) from table1 group by idAction;
```

note: idAction is one of the measures values in the cube.

How to convert that query into MDX query?

This is my first time to MDX query. please help me to learn MDX.

Answer (score 1):

We need to know what your cube structure is.
If we assume there is a measure in your cube called IdCount, that is the crrect aggregation type, then the mdx will be:

```
SELECT 
  [idAction].[idAction].MEMBERS ON ROWS,
  [Measures].[IdCount] ON COLUMNS 
FROM [YourCube];
```

Answer (score 1):

As whytheq suggests we must know the structure of the cube, in order to provide a better answer.
 Using Adventure Works cube, assume that you want to order the internet sales amount per calendar year (NON EMPTY: exclude NULL values).

```
SELECT 
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] ON 0,--rows
 NON EMPTY Order
(
[Date].[Calendar Year].MEMBERS,
[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],BDESC
) 
ON 1--Columns
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Result

```
            Internet Sales Amount
All Periods    $29,358,677.22
CY 2007        $9,791,060.30
CY 2008        $9,770,899.74
CY 2006        $6,530,343.53
CY 2005        $3,266,373.66
```